# inverse Fourier transform of product of two functions

Tags: fourier-analysis

What is the inverse Fourier transform of $i\omega f(\omega)g(\omega)$?

is it just $\frac{d}{dt}(f(t)\cdot g(t))$ or will I end up with some kind of convolution?

Comment: You will end up with some kind of convolution

Comment: The IFT will be $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-t')g(t')\,dt'=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t')g(t-t')\,dt'$$

Comment: Allright. Thank's a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be a convolution by the [convolution theorem for inverse Fourier transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem#Convolution_theorem_for_inverse_Fourier_transform):

$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(i\omega \hat{f}(\omega)\hat{g}(\omega)\right)(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\hat{f}(\omega)\hat{g}(\omega)\right)(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\widehat{(f*g)}(\omega)\right)(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(f*g)(t)$

Just remember (and never forget) that convolution turns into multiplication after applying the Fourier transform and vice versa.